# ATS - datatype declaration parametrized by `int` sort

Tags: types, ats

I would like to declare an ATS datatype representing a fixed point number with given precision and point. Here is how I thought it should be done:

```
datatype fixed (t:int, n:int) = {n:nat} fixed (t, n) of (t)
```

Here I am thinking as though `int` represents the "sort" of all integer-like types, which is convenient for doing arithmetic operations. `{n:nat}`, I think, declares that `fixed` is a dependent type parametrized by the natural number `n`, which will indicate the bit index for which the point occurs. Then `fixed (t, n)` indicates that the type itself is parametrized by the integer type, `t`, that we choose and the index value `n`, and the constructor must be applied to some element of the type `t`. Clearly, my understanding is flawed, because I receive the following error after running `acc arithmetic.dats`:

```
arithmetic.dats: 6:60-61

6| datatype fixed (t:int, n:int) = {n:nat} fixed (t, n) of (t)
                                                            ^ 
error: the static expression is of the sort 
  t@ype

patsopt(TRANS2): there are [1] errors in total.
  exit(ATS): (1025)
```

This is strange to me because I intended `t` to be of the sort `int`. What would be the proper way to declare this datatype?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
datatype fixed (int(*sort*)) = {n:nat} fixed (n) of (int(*type*))
```

The confusion may be due to `int` being both a sort and a type in ATS.